# append to/insert a row with an index value into an indexed dataframe without losing the index name?

Tags: pandas, indexing

Given the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'myindex':1,'a':2,'b':3},{'myindex':2,'a':22,'b':33}]).set_index('myindex')
```

and a new row:

```
new_row = {'myindex':11,'a':20,'b':30}
```

Is the most parsimonious way of adding `new_row` to the dataframe to `reset` the index, `append` without `myindex` as the index, and then reindex with a `set_index` to `myindex`?

```
df = df.reset_index().append(new_row,ignore_index=True).set_index('myindex')
```

I tried the `pandas` method `concat` but it wipes out the `index` `name` while adding a new column named `myindex` consisting of NaN in all but the new_row.  I tried doing a:

```
new_row_myindex = new_row['myindex']
del new_row['myindex']
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(new_row,index=[new_row_myindex])])
```

But that drops the index's name `myindex`.

I tried the `DataFrame` method `insert` but, unique among similar methods, it has no `axis` parameter and is therefore limited to inserting columns (quite curious when you think about it).

Comment: Probably something like `df.loc[11] = {'a': 20, 'b': 30}` would be the standard approach. (Naturally some programatic unpacking of arguments could be done from the `dict`)

Comment: If one had a number of such dictionaries to append/insert would that, in a loop, remain the standard approach?

Comment: No building a separate DataFrame of the same structure and appending once without `ignore_index` would be the approach: `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([{'myindex':11,'a':20,'b':30}, {'myindex':12,'a':20,'b':30}]).set_index('myindex'))`

Comment: The single row approach would necessitate doing the `del` operation as I described in the question, lest one receive the error:  `ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (2)`.  This, again, raises the mysterious absence of an `axis` argument for the `DataFrame` method `insert`.  But at least I got my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the first (key, value) pair in the dictionaries of new rows always `myindex`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
df = df.append((pd.Series({'myindex':11,'a':20,'b':30}, name=new_row['myindex'])[1:]))

# Output
          a     b
myindex         
1         2     3
2        22     33
11       20     30
```